# Can not retrive user birthday using aplication access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-permissions

Scope has `user_birthday` and `email` permission but answer has only email and no birthday.
If I use `user access token` then birthday exists but I need to retrieve it using `application access token`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The app access token has the limited powers . It can fetch only the basic details and post feed on user wall. may be it could not fetch the bday details for you.  You can read more about app access token on the developers site.